# SeleniumHQ stuct in Checking Resource aliases

Tags: automated-testing, selenium, hudson

I want to run testsuite from Hudson, for that i have installed seleniumhq plugin and configured in hudson, but when i run the hudson it stuck on "Checking Resource aliases" step.

```
 Started by user <<<user>>>
     java -jar D:\usr\local\apache-tomcat-6.0.20\seleniumlib\selenium-server.jar -htmlSuite *firefox http://172.16.12.45:8081/applicationname/ /usr/local/apache-tomcat-6.0.20/seleniumtest/selenium-xml/TestSuite.html.bak /usr/local/apache-tomcat-6.0.20/seleniumtest/selenium-html/TestResult.html
    [seleniumtest] $ java -jar D:\usr\local\apache-tomcat-6.0.20\seleniumlib\selenium-server.jar -htmlSuite *firefox http://172.16.12.45:8081/applicationanem/ /usr/local/apache-tomcat-6.0.20/seleniumtest/selenium-xml/TestSuite.html.bak /usr/local/apache-tomcat-6.0.20/seleniumtest/selenium-html/TestResult.html
    Mar 2, 2013 2:36:04 PM org.openqa.grid.selenium.GridLauncher main
    INFO: Launching a standalone server
    14:36:04.187 INFO - Java: Sun Microsystems Inc. 16.3-b01
    14:36:04.187 INFO - OS: Windows 2003 5.2 x86
    14:36:04.187 INFO - v2.30.0, with Core v2.30.0. Built from revision dc1ef9c
    14:36:04.281 INFO - RemoteWebDriver instances should connect to: http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub
    14:36:04.281 INFO - Version Jetty/5.1.x
    14:36:04.281 INFO - Started HttpContext[/selenium-server/driver,/selenium-server/driver]
    14:36:04.281 INFO - Started HttpContext[/selenium-server,/selenium-server]
    14:36:04.281 INFO - Started HttpContext[/,/]
    14:36:04.343 INFO - Started org.openqa.jetty.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler@276af2
    14:36:04.343 INFO - Started HttpContext[/wd,/wd]
    14:36:04.359 INFO - Started SocketListener on 0.0.0.0:4444
    14:36:04.359 INFO - Started org.openqa.jetty.jetty.Server@f81843
    jar:file:/D:/usr/local/apache-tomcat-6.0.20/seleniumlib/selenium-server.jar!/customProfileDirCUSTFFCHROME
    14:36:04.468 INFO - Preparing Firefox profile...
    14:36:05.531 INFO - Launching Firefox...
    14:36:06.140 INFO - Checking Resource aliases
```

Hudson in Windows 2003 server, Tomcat 7.0.5, Firefox 18

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Save the Test File as Test Suite not as Test case. Run the Hudson. Hopefully you will not be struck up this time !

Comment: Now i'm getting "Failed to copy /usr/local/apache-tomcat-6.0.20/seleniumtest\usr\local\apache-tomcat-6.0.20\sele‌​niumtest\selenium-html\TestResult.html to C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\.hudson\jobs\SeleniumTest\seleniumhq\index.ht‌​ml"

Comment: But in Publish Selenium Report input field i have given only seleniumtest\selenium-html\TestResult.html